# sliding window traverses downward on column instead of rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sliding-window

I am trying to build a sliding window that traverses along each row using the snippet below:

Read data from excel:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('link_to_excel', header=None)
vals = pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(data)
col_count, row_count = vals.shape
```

Data from excel looks like this:

```
i = [[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
     [11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
     [21 22 23 23 25 26 27 28 29 30]
     [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
     [21 22 23 23 25 26 27 28 29 30]
     [21 22 23 23 25 26 27 28 29 30]
     [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]]
```

Sliding window function:

```
def rolling(a, window):
    shape = (a.size - window + 1, window)
    strides = (a.itemsize, a.itemsize)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides, writeable=False)
```

When I run:

```
window = 6
print(rolling(i, window))
```

I get a sliding window that looks like this (traverses down column on `i`):

```
[[ 1 11 21  1 21 21]
 [11 21  1 21 21  1]
 [21  1 21 21  1  2]
 [ 1 21 21  1  2 12]
 [21 21  1  2 12 22]]
```

The desired sliding window I'm looking for based on the *first* row from `i`:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5  6]
 [2 3 4 5 6  7]
 [3 4 5 6 7  8]
 [4 5 6 7 8  9]
 [5 6 7 8 9 10]]
```

When I generate `i` using `np.random.randint(1, 31, size=(7, 10))`, I get the desired result I looking for.

How can I get the desired sliding window when reading from excel?

Output of `print(i.ravel(order='K'))`

```
[ 1 11 21  1 21 21  1  2 12 22  2 22 22  2  3 13 23  3 23 23  3  4 14 24
  4 24 24  4  5 15 25  5 25 25  5  6 16 26  6 26 26  6  7 17 27  7 27 27
  7  8 18 28  8 28 28  8  9 19 29  9 29 29  9 10 20 30 10 30 30 10]
```

Output of `print(i.shape)`

```
(7,10)
```

Sample [`excel`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fix4zu6NFI9qZNgx--8evlRlWiRUiZkYGS7LwWE1_b8/edit?usp=sharing) sheet

Comment: As described the problem isn't reproducable.  As you found out a generated array doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Sorry, but if I have described the exact method I used in getting the data, the function I used to process it, the result I am getting and desired output I'm looking.

Comment: When you generate i using the generated array, you get an array with commas. Am I missing something? Your array above looks like as text string of numbers.

Comment: @run-out The type of each of the numbers is `<class 'numpy.int64'>`

Comment: @run-out, the arrays without commas are typical displays of `numpy` arrays.

Comment: We don't have your `excel` source, so can't derived your `vals` variable.  Also the jump from there to `i` is unclear.  There's something different about that `i` that the display isn't showing, for example the order might differ.  I wonder what `print(i.ravel(order='K'))` looks like.

Comment: @hpaulj See update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have `xlrd` support installed on my pandas, but exporting it to `csv`:

```
In [168]: data = pd.read_csv('../Downloads/Untitled spreadsheet - Sheet1.csv', h
     ...: eader=None)
In [169]: data
Out[169]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
1  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
2  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
3   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
4  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
5  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
6   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
In [170]: data = data.values
```

The `strides` shows it is `order F`, as does ravel with order 'K'

```
In [171]: data.strides
Out[171]: (8, 56)
In [172]: data.ravel('K')
Out[172]: 
array([ 1, 11, 21,  1, 21, 21,  1,  2, 12, 22,  2, 22, 22,  2,  3, 13, 23,
        3, 23, 23,  3,  4, 14, 24,...])

In [175]: data.ravel('C')
Out[175]: 
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19, 20, 21, 22,...])

In [177]: rolling(data.ravel('C'),6)
Out[177]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       ...
```

I haven't seen the `order` of dataframe values discussed before.  But since a DataFrame is a collection of Series, the columns, it makes sense that the 2d array version will be order 'F', with values going down the columns.

You want to `roll` across the columns, so you will need to change the order of the array.